# Long URLs from Twitter feeds without making additional API calls/HTTP requests

Tags: twitter, rss, feed, url-shortener

Is there any built-in way to get the long, expanded URL from a twitter RSS feed? Right now the feed lists all the urls as `http://t.co...`. I'd like to do what the Twitter display does and display the long URLs; I'd also like to avoid having to do either an API call or HTTP request for each URL in the feed. Ideally, I'd also like to avoid using the Twitter API directly but if that's the only way, so be it.

## Clarification

I'm not interested in doing a separate request for every single t.co link, or calling the Twitter API. I was hoping there was a ***single*** request I could make that would include the long URLs in the metadata (or even provide the tweet in full expanded form as it appears on Twitter). Turns out the way to do this is by requesting the JSON version from search.twitter.com rather than the RSS feed, and tacking on `include_entities=True`.

## Rewrite, hopefully this makes it more clear

I'm using http://search.twitter.com/search.rss to get a feed of tweets matching a search term. The feed contains only the shortened t.co urls. Is there a way to modify my request so that the tweets contain the expanded URLs instead?

The goal is to do **just *one* request** rather than having to go through the tweets and parse each t.co url separately (especially since for a feed with several dozen t.co urls, that means several dozen separate requests). If necessary, I am willing to use the Twitter API directly to do the search instead of using RSS, but for my purposes using a feed is more ideal.

Comment: "Any built-in way"? Built into what?

Comment: Built into Twitter. That is, a way to get the long URLs without having to do post-processing.

Comment: Yeah guys, it's **not** an exact duplicate. Before asking this question I could easily come with three straightforward ways of expanding **any** shortened URL and that's not what I cared about. I wanted to know how to do it without making additional requests. The exact duplicate does **not** answer that question.

Comment: what does this mean then?  "Ideally, I'd also like to avoid using the Twitter API directly but if that's the only way, so be it." So, you didn't want to use an external API or even call the twitter API. Frankly question was vague. Duplicate link is more direct and helps people who stumble into this post.

Comment: @Chamilyan In other words, if I had to call a direct request to get the results (I'm not familiar with the API but let's say it was something like `Twitter.get_tweets("apple")`) that would be cool, but I didn't want to have to pull in the feed and *then* unshorten each t.co URL. The other question explicitly asks, "How can I unshorten t.co URLs". Here's a good analogy: the similar question was like "How do I slice a loaf of bread I just purchased?" Mine was, "Is it possible for me to purchase 20 loaves of bread that are already sliced?"

Comment: If you were familiar with the Twitter API, you would'nt be asking the question in the way you did, so it was vague and I decided that the other question gave more clear direction. You specifically said you didn't want to call the Twitter API. You should have said, I would rather make one API call instead of many.

Comment: @Chamilyan That was what I was getting at in the statement "I'd also like to avoid having to do either an API call or HTTP request for each URL in the feed." Part of the confusion was probably also referring to the Twitter API when I really meant not having to use a Twitter module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Twitter does not offer a `urls` entity in its RSS responses, nor does the `include_entities` option appear to work. You'll have to use a different response format e.g. JSON (with which you can use the [`include_entities`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities) option which includes an `entities['urls'][n]['expanded_url']` object), or "unshorten" the URLs yourself after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without using the Twitter API directly. You can use one of several resources,

http://expandurl.appspot.com/

API call prototype : `http://expandurl.appspot.com/expand?url=`

http://longurl.org

API call prototype : `http://api.longurl.org/v2/expand?url=`

http://unshort.me/

API call prototype: `http://api.unshort.me/?r=http://`

of course you can also use the Twitter API directly for this as Jordan mentioned by including `&include_entities=1` or `true` as a parameter to some calls.

also try to CURL the URL and see what information you can gleam from that. I think this pretty much exhausts the options.

Comment: Sorry, I thought "I'd also like to avoid having to do either an API call or HTTP request for each URL in the feed" implied that I understood how to expand URLs already. Perhaps I should have written it as "I understand that I can expand t.co urls individually by using either an API or making an HTTP request and parsing the 302 response. I don't want to do that for every single t.co url in the feed."

Comment: @Jordan Reiter . I don't understand why you downvoted this answer. You said you didn't want to call the Twitter API directly so I gave you ways to unshorten the link without calling the API directly and I included a way to make one single API call AND I included a way to make no API calls at all. I litterlaly gave you every way you can go about doing this. It's a perfecttly valid answer. I don't want to start a war here but it's obvious your spiteful of the fact that your answer was marked duplicate so you decided to downvote mine. :/

Comment: You're right I was a bit annoyed, it was an overreaction and I'll remove the downvote when I can. The bit about the include_entities does answer the question but was already posted as an answer. The remainder of your answer didn't answer the question I was trying to ask, which is how to get the long urls without making any additional requests.

Comment: all well that ends well. If you edit your question , I'll be able to upvote it.